# Integral identity satisfied by complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-number-theory, analytic-functions

Let $x$, $\alpha$, and $T$ be positive parameters. I'm trying to prove that the function $I(x, \alpha, T)$ defined as:
$$
I(x, \alpha, T) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\alpha-iT}^{\alpha+iT} \frac{x^s}{s} ds
$$
satisfies the identity:
$$
I(x, \alpha, T) = \int_{-\infty}^{\log x}e^{\alpha y}\frac{\sin Ty}{\pi y} dy.
$$
I tried using the residue theorem, looking at the square (punched at the origin) of vertices $iT$, $-iT$, $\alpha-iT$ and $\alpha+iT$, but I didn't get any progress.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hint: write $\frac{1}{s}$ as $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t$, and $x^s$ as $e^{s\log(x)}$, and use Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Nice, I managed to do it with your hint! Thanks @BrunoB.